# Page comes up blank using w3 total cache

Tags: comments, pages, plugin-w3-total-cache

Im using the W3 Total Cache plugin on my site, and I made page using the wp_list_comments and for some reason the page keeps coming up blank, it comes back after I disable the plugin but when i enable it everything goes blank again does anyone have a suggestion on how iI can fix this, im new to this plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off caching for your wp_list_comments template by placing `define('DONOTCACHEPAGE', true);` at the top of the page.

Other constants available on a per page or template basis are:

- `define('DONOTCACHEDB', true);`

  Disables database caching for given page.
- `define('DONOTMINIFY', true);`

  Disables minify for a given page.
- `define('DONOTCDN', true);`

  Disables content delivery network for a given page.
- `define('DONOTCACHCEOBJECT', true);`

  Disables object cache for a given page.

Comment: Thank you for replying, ok i kinda figured out whats causing it to go blank, im using this code <?php wp_list_comments('per_page=23&callback=mytheme_comment', get_comments()); ?> and its get_comments(); thats making the page come back blank, once i take getcomments() out the page works fine, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please let me know what do you mean by wp_list_comments template ?